# Is hyperledger composer meant for production

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Based on the training videos I have watched, they all talk about the composer as something you use to "define and test your business network", but it almost feels like once its verified and tested, you throw it away and use something more serious.  Am I wrong?  Even term "playground" feels "experimental" -- something you mess with, but thats all.  So, would you build a production system based on composer?  How do you split it into multiple machines for redundancy?  If composer is so slick and the "obvious" choice for building hyperledger applications, when would you NOT use it and use Fabric or Sawtooth instead?  I am trying to get started and dont want to waste time on the wrong path.  If you were to build a "serious" supply chain application with multiple players, what framework  approach would you take? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Composer is not a separate platform. It uses Hyperledger Fabric "under the hood". The main problem with Composer is it does not have all the options and features of Fabric exposed in the Composer interface. So, it allows for rapid prototyping at the expense of flexibility. Composer has an impressive user interface.

Unfortunately, Composer is now in maintenance mode with no new features being put into it.  See https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125

I would consider Hyperledger Sawtooth or Hyperledger Fabric for permissioned blockchain applications.

Comment: echo what @Dan wrote and the link provided. A lot of the good concepts in Composer (make it easier to write applications, smart contracts), are being added to Fabric (as I 'speak') and would suggest to download it (master branch) and take a look at it, as the new programming model as the platform to move forward.  A very good use case is described in the Fabric docs, explaining the use case, design concepts, architectural approach and development practice using the new Fabric programming model https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developapps/scenario.html. Hope this helps.